# Run a Mathematica program in a cluster

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, cloud, cluster-computing

Suppose I want to run a Mathematica program that I wrote, in a cluster or using a cloud computing solution. Can Mathematica programs run on their own without a license? And in case they don't, do cloud-computing solutions come packaged with the resources to do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you may be interested in gridMathematica: http://www.wolfram.com/products/gridmathematica/

David

Answer (score 6):

It's also worthwhile pointing out http://www.nimbisservices.com/catalog/cloud-services-mathematica who offer cloud computing services using V7.

Comment: But it seems this is only for Mathematica7, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Spoke about a week too soon.  You'll have seen this http://www.wolfram.com/gridmathematica/.